# C++ question & answer script that reacts on answers from user input help (Newbie)

Tags: c++, string

i want the application to react with the right answer. I tried different things but since i don't know a lot anymore im kinda stuck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// animegenres: Romance,shounen,shoujo.
string Romance = "Domestic girlfriend, Plastic memories, Fruits basket" ;
string shounen = "Sword art online, Attack on titan, Nanatsu No taizai";
string Shoujo = "Fruits basket, Haruku Nagizaki's secret" ;
string antwoord = "";


cout << "Hello which genre do you want?"<< endl;
getline(cin , antwoord);
if ((antwoord == shounen) || (antwoord == Shoujo)) {
cout <<shounen <<endl;
}
else
cout << "Wil je misschien een andere lijst?" << endl;
 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, when declaring a string that won't change, declare it as `const`, e.g. `const string Romance`

Comment: I highly recommend placing the genre names into `std::vector<string>`.  Searching a string for *containing* a genre is more difficult.

Comment: We're not going to guess what specific exact, input you're providing to your program, what specific exact output you're expecting as a result, and finally *why* that should be the case based on what you think you're code should be doing. *all* of that belongs *in your question*.

Comment: I recommend that your strings be all lower case or all upper case.  When you input a string convert (or `transform`) it to all one case.  This lets you find things with only one comparison.  Remember, in C++ strings are case sensitive:  "Fruits" != "fruits".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Alright, Thanks for replying. I will ask my question better.
I want the program to ask the question: From which genre do you want a question?
Then i want the person to be able to give 3 answers. I want the application to give the answers based on the answer the user put in. like if i put in Romance, that the application gives the answer: Domestic girlfriend, Plastic memories, Fruits basket (This information is stored in the string) i tried with the code that i know in short to do that but im stuck with that. I hope i clarified my question better. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't ask for full genre names.  Ask for letters a, b, c or d.  Lower- or uppercase.

Comment: @zkoza Alright.